# Reading json file sub-levels

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I need some assistance in reading a json file in vs2019 vb.net. I have figured out most of it but there is a sub-level I don't know how to code to read it. I am using the Newtonsoft.json reference library.

Here is a sample of the json data:

```json
[
    {
    "checkDate": "2020-02-07",
    "periodBeginDate": "2020-01-27",
    "periodEndDate": "2020-02-02",
    "earnings": [
      {
        "earningCode": "REG",
        "hours": 0.0000,
        "rate": 0.000000,
        "amount": 55.00,
        "chargeDate": null,
        "jobCode": "",
        "in1": null,
        "out1": null,
        "in2": null,
        "out2": null,
        "memo": "",
        "internalMemo": "",
        "costCenters": [
        {
        "level": 1,
        "levelCode": "DEPT",
        "costCenterCode": "Gradall operator"
        }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "costCenters": [
      {
        "level": 1,
        "levelCode": "DEPT",
        "costCenterCode": "Gradall operator"
      }
    ],
    "divisionKey": {
      "companyCode": "IT1",
      "divisionCode": "001"
    },
    "employeeNumber": "999"
  }
]
```

As you can see, there could be multiple cost centers, one at the root level and one under the earnings section. I need to get both. The root level one (and the other data) I am able to get with the code below. But I am unable to figure out how to code for the "cost centers" under "earnings". Do I need an entirely new class? And does it go under "earnings"? I am new at reading json files so any help would be appreciated.

```
Public Class CheckData
Public Property EmployeeNumber As String = ""
Public Property DivisionKey As divisionKeys
Public Property Earnings() As List(Of Earning)
Public Property CostCenters() As List(Of CostCenter)

<JsonProperty("periodEndDate")>
Public Property PPDEndDate As Date?

<JsonProperty("checkDate")>
Public Property CheckDate As Date?
Public Class divisionKeys
    <JsonProperty("divisionKey")>
    Public Property divisionKey() As Object
    Public Property companyCode As String = ""
    Public Property divisionCode As String = ""
End Class

Public Class CostCenter
    <JsonProperty("costCenters")>
    Public Property costCenters() As Object
    Public Property startDate As Date
    Public Property levelCode As String = ""
    Public Property costCenterCode As String = ""
End Class

Public Class Earning
    <JsonProperty("earnings")>
    Public Property earnings1() As Object
    Public Property earningCode As String = ""
    Public Property hours As Decimal
    Public Property amount As Decimal
End Class


Private Sub GetJsonData()

    SecFileName = "PayrollData.json"
    Dim jsonString = IO.File.ReadAllText(PathJson & SecFileName)
    Dim AllEmpl = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of CheckData))(jsonString)

    Try
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConnString)
            cn.Open()

            For Each Emp In AllEmpl
                EarnCount = Emp.Earnings.Count

                For i = 0 To EarnCount - 1

                    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Insert Into tblFTEImportBase (EmpId, FacNumPay, JobCode, PaycheckDate, PPDEndDate, EarnType, EarnHours, EarnAmt)
          Values (@EmpId, @FacNumPay, @JobCode, @CheckDate, @PPDEndDate, @EarnType, @EarnHours, @EarnAmt);", cn)
                        With cmd.Parameters
                            .Add("@EmpId", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = Emp.EmployeeNumber
                            .Add("@FacNumPay", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = Emp.DivisionKey.companyCode

                            For cc = 0 To Emp.CostCenters.Count - 1
                                Select Case Emp.CostCenters(cc).levelCode

                                    Case "DEPT"
                                        .Add("@JobCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = Emp.CostCenters(cc).costCenterCode

                                        'Case "JC"
                                        '    .Add("@DeptNum", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = Emp.CostCenters(cc).costCenterCode
                                End Select
                            Next

                            If IsDBNull(Emp.CheckDate) = True Or Emp.CheckDate Is Nothing Then
                                .Add("@CheckDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DBNull.Value
                            Else
                                .Add("@CheckDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = Emp.CheckDate
                            End If

                            If IsDBNull(Emp.PPDEndDate) = True Or Emp.PPDEndDate Is Nothing Then
                                .Add("@PPDEndDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DBNull.Value
                            Else
                                .Add("@PPDEndDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = Emp.PPDEndDate
                            End If

                            EarnTypeTest = Emp.Earnings(0).earningCode

                            .Add("@EarnType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = Emp.Earnings(i).earningCode
                            .Add("@EarnHours", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Emp.Earnings(i).hours

                            .Add("@EarnAmt", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Emp.Earnings(i).amount
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        End With

                    End Using
                Next
            Next
            cn.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        SuccessFlag = "N"
        Errormsg = ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to first generate the class using the Paste Special tool from VS2019 [image: Paste Special]

This will autogenerate a class that can handle that specific type of JSON (Try using a JSON that has its full range of variables, arrays, etc)

After that, just deserialize it like this:

```
Dim yourObjJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of YourJSONClass)(<JSON as String>)
```

If you want you can check the [JObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) documentantion too.